# Magento site showing white page before load content

Tags: magento-1.9

I have magento version 1.9.2.1, When I load any page(cms, search, product page) in frontend then it display blank white page for 5-10 seconds after that it start loading content.

I checked in network section (in browser developer mode), TTFB showing there 5-10 seconds for all page (even a simple cms page which has only static content).

I have also installed Lesti-FPC plugin and all cache are enabled from admin section. And Compilation mode also enabled.

I have two question :

**First** : How to improve TTFB.

**Seconds** : How to start to load content, so that no white page display to customer while loading content.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216743/tweaking-magento-for-performance This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with your server respond or wait time. This must be some glitches towards server end.

check for server respond, load and wait time
you can verify these all by going https://tools.pingdom.com/